# ¿Por qué el servicio system/connect de drupal 7 devuelve una página en blanco?

Tags: webservice, drupal, drupal7

Necesito crear un servicio web en drupal 7 que contenga el recurso system/connect (para mostrar los usuarios logueados) pero a la hora de consumirlo devuelve una página en blanco. ¿A qué se puede deber esto?

He probado con el recurso usuario y funciona bien (devuelve todos los usuarios del sistema)

la url que estoy utilizando para consumir es la siguiente

```
https://localhost/drupal/x_login/system/connect
```

Donde `x_login` es el endpoint. Además existen usuarios conectados en el momento de consumir el servicio.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que el system/connect es utilizado solo para saber el usuario actual que está conectado. Por ejemplo, si tu estás logueado y envías al servidor rest de Drupal en el metodo POST, el system/connect debe darte el CSFR-Token de tu usuario, no el de todos los usuarios que están conectados.

En youtube, tengo unos videos relacionados con este tema el cual te puede interesar.
[Modulo Services Drupal 7 1/2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ocBMAmVkqAE&list=PLtg6DxcGyHSvMUUdfGN1st1yOFV1UJGnG&index=2)